# jQuery - change table cells position

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I change via jquery the  cells position from `1  2` to `2  1` ?

```
<table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#mytable tr td:eq(0)').appendTo('#mytable tr');
```

The **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8V4wb/1/)**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change all the second `td` to first position in your table, then you can use:

```
$.each($('#mytable tr td:eq(1)'), function() {
     $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
})
```

---

Actually, above code will not work if your table have more than one `<tr>` element, if that is the case then you need to use `.find()`:

```
$('#mytable tr').find('td:eq(1)').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9mP/)**

References: [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) , [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) , [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) , [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 1):

with append

http://jsfiddle.net/F7HmQ/1/

```
$(function(){
   var td = $("td").first() ;
    $("tr").first().append(td);    
});
```